# Printing out letter sequences given letters - python

Tags: python, for-loop

In a practice exam question, we are given the following:

```
ALPHABET = "ABCD" # letters to use in sequences 
seq = 3 * [ "" ]
letterSeqs = [ ] # list of all the letter sequences

for seq[0] in ALPHABET:
    for seq[1] in ALPHABET:
        for seq[2] in ALPHABET:
            letterSeqs.append("".join(seq))
```

We are supposed to estimate the total number of entries in the list letterSeqs as well as the first and last entries. Can anyone explain how the code works?

Thanks!

Comment: Not after it runs they aren't.

Comment: Have you tried running it? Perhaps putting in a few `print` statements to see what values are where?

Comment: What, specifically, are you unclear on?

Comment: This is not a good exam question, in my opinion

Comment: @CDspace I tried running it and the answers I get are 64, 'AAA', 'DDD'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is odd code, but legal…

First:

```
seq = 3 * [ "" ]
```

… creates an empty string, and a list consisting of three references to that empty string.

Later, you do this:

```
for seq[0] in ALPHABET:
```

That's the tricky bit. It loops over `ALPHABET`, assigning each of the 4 letters in turn to `seq[0]`. Normally, you use a variable as the loop variable, not a complex target like this. In fact, I'm guessing the teacher did this specifically to throw you off. However, it *does* turn out to be useful, sort of.

And then, for each of those 4 iterations, you do this:

```
    for seq[1] in ALPHABET:
```

That again loops 4 times, per outer loop, so that's a total of 16 middle loops. And then, for each of those 16, you do this:

```
        for seq[2] in ALPHABET:
```

That again loops 4 times, per middle loop, for a total of 64 inner loops.

And then, for each one, you do this:

```
            letterSeqs.append("".join(seq))
```

At this point, `seq` will always be a list of 3 single-character strings. That's the payoff for using `seq[0]` as your loop variable. That being said, there are much better ways to do the same thing. Just use `for i`, `for j`, and `for k` and this could be `i+j+k` instead. (And if you want to generalize to something other than 3 strings, the static nested loop structure is the hard part, not the separate variables…)

So, it will `join` into a single 3-character string. Which you then append to the empty list.

So, at the end, you've got a list of 64 3-character strings.

Comment: I was totally ignorant of the fact that the ``target_list`` item in the definition of a for-loop : ``for_stmt ::= "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite `` could be an indexed element in a list. However, the sentence in the doc, **Each item in turn is assigned to the target list using the standard rules for assignments** covers this case, but I think it should have been more, or rather clearly, explicit. The doc is bad on this point. What do you think about this ? Did you know this peculiarity before this question ?

Answer (score 2):

```
for _ in container:
```

will run `len(container)` times. As you're nested three deep, it runs

```
len(container) ** 3 == 4 ** 3 == 64
```

times. Each time you append one `str` object, `"".join(seq)`, so the length at the end will be 64.

When the first item is appended, all positions in `seq` have the first value in `ALPHABET`, so the item is `"AAA"`. At the end, they all have the last value from `ALPHABET`, so the last item will be `"DDD"`.